# Freeradius + external php script

Tags: php, external, freeradius

I'm trying to use external script in freeradius default file. When I check PHP variables, (`$User`, `$Pass` etc) are empty.

What is wrong?

#### Default file

```
authorize {

preprocess

update control { 
Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/rad_log.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}'`      
}
```

#### PHP file

```
<?php
  $User = getenv("USER-NAME");
  $Pass = getenv("USER-PASSWORD");

  echo $User;
  echo $Pass;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution..

```
update control {    
    Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/rad_log.php %{User-Name} %{User-Password}`      
}
```

**Php File**

```
<?PHP
$User = $argv[1];
$Pass = $argv[2];
?>
```